# Using force and buttons

Tags: arduino, circuit-design

So I am currently trying to make an interactive mobile phone cover that communicates with a game on your phone. The inputs to the game will be push buttons on either side of the cover. What I am interested in knowing is: how can one measure the force that a button is pressed with? Or alternatively, how could some sort of force sensor be incorporated into or near the button(s)? It would be interesting to incorporate force into this mix as well, and use that as another input to the game.

Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: @jsotola ah i see what you mean, I will fix it

Comment: Such force sensitive switches are readily available, though still a bit pricy. Most change in resistance with applied force.  A simple multi-input ADC or controller chip could do the detecting, then a tiny smt chip (for e.g. an ATtiny brand) could communicate with the phone app. If a thin flex PCB were used it all might fit under the phone cover. See one example of a force sensitive switch/resistor here: https://www.jameco.com/z/1696-Pololu-1-2-Inch-Circular-Force-Sensing-Resistor_2128260.html?%20CID=GOOG&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_enosuPy5QIVGYeGCh2nmwssEAQYBSABEgIPCPD_BwE

Comment: @Nedd Thank you for your suggestion, Nedd. I have experimented with using this type of FSR, but found it to be not that accurate and very fragile (especially at the legs of the sensor). I think I even broke a few like that, and yes as you mentioned they are a little pricey. I was actually looking for a force sensor that somehow was in a similar size or shape to a button. Alternatively, I also considered using velostat: like wrapping it around the cover but this wouldn't be that accurate either and isn't  that readily available